# Pandas calculation for each row depending on row before

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have two DataFrames and I need to do following calculation:
I want to calculate the twr.loc['20151215'] in twr by multiplying the 100 above with the value pct.loc['20151216']. This should be done for each cell seperately and thenn continue for the next row. This is what I've tried which won't work:

```
for eachdate in range(1, len(daterange)):
         date1_lbl = TWRR.index[eachdate]
         date2_lbl = TWRR.index[eachdate+1]
         TWRR.loc[date2_lbl] = TWRR.loc[date1_lbl] * (1 + pct_change.loc[date2_lbl])

print pct

              a          b          c         d
Date                                               
2015-12-15       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2015-12-16 -0.006232 -0.011392 -0.010945 -0.010373
2015-12-17 -0.011626 -0.014725 -0.016674 -0.006613
2015-12-18 -0.012519 -0.015595 -0.014799 -0.003768

print twr
                a     b      c      d
2015-12-15    100    100    100    100
2015-12-16    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2015-12-17    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2015-12-18    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

So it should first fill out '2015-12-16' like so:

```
2015-12-16    99.99376    98.8608    98.90550    0.989627
```

And Next it should calculate '2015-12-17' by using the previously calculated row... I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `cumprod`:

```
pct.a.fillna(0).add(1).cumprod().mul(100)
```

[image]

Comment: I understand your line, and I'm new to those function. I'll still have to try it out. Thanks for pointing them out tom. But is there a way to point out to the first line of twr in case of starting values not being all the same as 100 ? And what does the a stand for?

Comment: What you described in your question was calculating the growth of `100`.  That number is fairly arbitrary.  Insert whatever you'd like.  The far more important element is taking care of the returns.  When you accumulate, you want to multiply what you had by 1 + return.  `.add(1)` is doing just that.  Then I cumulate with `.cumprod()`.  At this point, what I have is the growth of `1`.  Multiplying it by anything else gives me the growth of that.

Comment: Your method requires that the starting value of a, b, c and d are all the same. Is there another way in case of it not being the same?